# access_control doesn't work

Tags: security, symfony, access-control

I'd like to protect route **/admin** with access_control but doesn't work , I can always get in without login.

**EDIT**

This is the route of admin :

```
admin_homepage:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/admin/index.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}/admin
```

If I remove **{_locale}** from the route the access_control work, How can I solve this ?
This is Security.yml

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_AUTEUR, ROLE_MODERATEUR]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email


firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:  main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: frontend_index
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: frontend_index
        remember_me:
            key:    %secret%

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
access_control:
    [...]
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

to

```
access_control:
    [...]
    - { path: ^/.*/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

(if you like, you can also use this)

```
access_contol:
    [...]
    - { path: ^/[a-z]{2}/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The reason is that security controls are performed with regex, so if you don't specify any prefix before"admin", the control will fail and anyone could be able to login.

Whit first version of my solution, any prefix before admin will be matched. With second, only a prefix with exactly two letters between a and z (lower case) will be matched (so, every locale)